why my code of caesar cipher don't work for the letter "z"
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))


def encrypt(text,shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for char in text:
        index = alphabet.index(char)
        new_index = index + shift
        if new_index > 25:  -------->>
            for numba in range(0,26):
                new_index = numba         
        cipher_text += alphabet[new_index]
        
    print(cipher_text)
        
encrypt(text,shift)

What is wrong with this code if i input "zulu" it encrypt it as "zzqz" instead of "ezqz", What is wrong here i cant figure it out.
I was expecting it to print "ezqz".

Please format your code properly

So if new_index is greater than 25, you... set new_index to 0, then set it to 1, then set it to 2, all the way until it reaches 25? Why are you doing that?

if new_index > 25: -------->> this is not valid Python syntax. [Edit] your code to have a [mre].

You want modulo https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

'zulu'.translate(t) == 'ezqz' for an appropriately defined translation table t, which str.maketrans and string.ascii_lowercase can help you create.

Solution 1
Here is the part of your code that is caused the error:
        if new_index > 25:
            for numba in range(0,26):
                new_index = numba         

Take a closer look at the for loop: it will run from 0 to 25. That means new_index will always be 25, which is corresponding to a letter 'z'. The fix is to use modulo arithmetic as Kenny pointed out. In additional to using modulo, a quick fix is to subtract 26 (that is the length of alphabet) from new_index in case of overflowing:
def encrypt(text,shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for char in text:
        index = alphabet.index(char)
        new_index = index + shift
        if new_index > 25:
            new_index = new_index - len(alphabet)
        cipher_text += alphabet[new_index]
        
    print(cipher_text)

Solution 2
This is the modulo approach which Kenny mentioned:
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def encrypt(text,shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for char in text:
        index = (alphabet.index(char) + shift) % len(alphabet)
        cipher_text += alphabet[index]

    print(cipher_text)


Thank you guys, appreciate your help i have just begun my programming journey and srry if it was a silly question and also i didn't expect the response to be this fast.

As your code is a combined form of stdin and function, I'm simplifying to function format.
I've removed the second iteration(nested). Instead 26 is subtracted from the new_index
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def encrypt(text,shift):
    text = text.lower()
    cipher_text = "" 
    for char in text:
        index = alphabet.index(char)
        new_index = index + shift
        if new_index > 25:
        
            # Subtract 26 from new_index if new_index > 26
            new_index = new_index -26

        cipher_text += alphabet[new_index]
    return cipher_text

r = encrypt('zulu', 5)
print(r) # Output : 'ezqz'

Additional tips:
Instead of typing all the alphabets in a list, you can simply declare as
alphabet = [chr(97+i) for i in range(26)]

